# How do I create a dropdownList from Provider ? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider, flutter-widget

I have created a city model, and have created a provider class for that,

```
class CityModel {
  String cityId;
  String cityName;

  CityModel({this.cityId, this.cityName});
}
```

This is the provider class

```
class CitiesProviders extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<CityModel> citiesData = [];

  void addData(CityModel data) {
    citiesData.add(data);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<String> get cityNames {
    List<String> names = [];
    citiesData.map((value) {
      names.add(value.cityName);
    });
    return names;
  }
}
```

I'm just looking to get the names of cities from the citiesData list and use that name list to create a dropdown.

```
DropdownButton<String>(
      value: currVal,
      items: Provider.of<CitiesProviders>(context)
          .cityNames
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (value) {
        currVal = value;
      },
    ),
```

But I'm not getting anything on the screen, also there is no error message. Am I doing everything correct ? Or is there a better way to do this ? Any suggestions and answers would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake!

```
List<String> get cityNames {
    List<String> names = [];
    citiesData.map((value) {
      names.add(value.cityName);
    }).toList(); // Added here
    return name)s;
  }
```

I added toList() and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you have:

```
class CitiesProviders extends ChangeNotifier {}
```

You should have:

```
class CitiesProviders with ChangeNotifier {}
```

I'm not seeing any other issues in the rest of your code but I'm still new to Flutter.